# ESLint indentation issue w/ export statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

consider the following statement:

```
export const sort = (state = 'SORTED_BY_DATE', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case C.SORT_COLORS:
      return action.sortBy
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I'm getting errors like (consider the line `return state`):

```
error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4   indent
```

It's also expective the `switch` statement to be shifted left two spaces.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Update the rules in your lint file? or turn linting off in your config.

Comment: That doesn't help me much.  Can you be a little more specific? My `indent` rule is 2.  The problem is the miscalculation of spaces.

Comment: You need to configure your IDE to indent to 2 spaces instead of 4 when you hit enter. You could manually try combinations of tab and shift+tab while selecting your lines to accordingly change the indentation.

Comment: Unsure if this is the issue, but the [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) mentions: *This rule has an object option: `SwitchCase` (default: 0) enforces indentation level for case clauses in switch statements*. Note the default is 0, so perhaps it wants your `case` to be at the same level as the `switch`.

Comment: @CRice that worked.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

needed to update the option `SwitchCase: 1`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19479664)

Comment: @Shanimal How do you figure? OP is the one that posted this, and it certainly is an answer. I'm getting to this from review as well.

Comment: Hi @jhpratt. I wasn't reviewing the question, but i feel both needed clarification. What does the OP mean by "fix". Why is the linter complaining about 4 spaces when config is "fixed" by changing it to 2? Why does the code already have two spaces? I was left wondering, what is `SwitchCase` and where does it belong? We know, but this doesn't explain it to someone who doesn't. I would have been satisfied with "I changed the SwitchCase option in `.eslintrc` as @CRice mentioned in a comment three minutes ago"...